# Vector space question clarification

Tags: vector-spaces

1)Is the set of invertible 2x2 matrices having real entries with matrix multiplication and with scalar multiplication vector space?

2)Is the set of invertible 2x2 matrices having real entries with matrix addition and with scalar multiplication vector space?

I don't quite understand question 1), does it mean vector addition a+b is defined by a.b? And what is the difference between the 2 questions?

Comment: like we have to show (V,+) is abelian right which it clearly isn't because there is no zero vector as its not invertible, but then what does the word "multiplication" above do so say it was matrix addition instead.

Comment: I think you can ignore the "with matrix multiplication" and just check if $aA$ is in the space, for all $A$ in the space and all scalars $a$.  If not, you are done. (Or, just observe whether or not there is a 0, as you have already done).  You can get a negative answer from these, so you do not have to decide what they want for addition (either $A+B$ or $AB$).

Comment: Show that the set is not closed under addition and this is enough to show that it is **not** a vector space.

Comment: Is the set of invertible 2x2 matrices having real entries with matrix (addition) and with scalar multiplication vector space? Im confused between this and above question, that means they are exactly the same?

Comment: @Rivaldo Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @gimusi its useful  but doesn't answer my question...

Comment: @Rivaldo both cases are not subspaces since they don’t have the zero matrix (which is not invertible)

Comment: @gimusi yep I get that, but what does it mean when it says 'matrix multiplication' is it that addition is defined as multiplication?

Comment: @Rivaldo Recall that by definition for a vector space we can define as “addition” any binary operation such that $v+w\in V$ https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space

Comment: @gimusi  see, because on mark scheme it said multiplication not commutative and no zero vector, not commutative part made me think that way, but didn't make sense

Comment: @Rivaldo Yes also not commutative part suffices to exclude that it is a vector space but the observation about zero vector also suffices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that for a subspace all the following three properties must be satisfied:

1) $\vec{0} \in W$

2) $\vec{v}+\vec{w} \in W$

3) $\vec{cv}\to c \cdot \vec{v} \ ,c \in \mathbb{R}$

but this is not a subspace since $$\vec{0}\notin W$$